# How to add pipeline().parameters to Lookup in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Lookup Activity in Azure Data Factory.
I have parameter "offset", which have initial value 5.
I want to use parameter value as Integer value in Lookup query, but failing. Please advice.

Original Static Lookup Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales.[Customers]
ORDER BY CustomerId OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

--Parameterized Lookup Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales.[Customers]
ORDER BY CustomerId @concat('OFFSET ', pipeline().parameters.offset,' ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY')
```

Error of ADF for parameterized Lookup:

```
A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 
'@concat'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 
'@concat'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data 
Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors= 
[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near '@concat'.,},],'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire SQL statement in an expression (using the Expression Builder):

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM sales.[Customers] ORDER BY CustomerId OFFSET ', pipeline().parameters.offset, ' ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the parameter as well

```
    SELECT *
FROM sales.[Customers]
ORDER BY CustomerId OFFSET @{pipeline().parameters.offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```